# Oracle database error -- ORA-00979: no es una expresión GROUP BY

Tags: database, oracle

i´m using oracle and this is my query

```
 select DISTINCT table1.rol, table3.descripcion
 from table1
 inner join table2 on (table2.IDUSUARIO = 1 and table1.IDUSUARIO = 1)
 left join table3 on table3.rol = table1.rol
 GROUP BY table1.rol ORDER BY table1.rol
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyxvc.png)

i need this

[imageResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMeTU.png)

Comment: Unlike mysqls extended group by, oracle must have in the group by all fields which are not aggregated in the select.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't paste links to pictures containing text. Instead, paste the text.

Comment: Please edit your question and put text versions of what you have in those images. You get an upvote if you do ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress repeating values is not really the task of SQL. This you would normally do in the application that connects to the database.

But it is possible like this:

```
select     case row_number() over (partition by table1.rol order by table3.descripcion) 
               when 1 then table1.rol
           end as rol,
           table3.descripcion
from       table1 
inner join table2 on table2.idusuario = table1.idusuario 
left join  table3 on table3.rol = table1.rol 
where      table1.idusuario = 1
group by   table1.rol, table3.descripcion
order by   table1.rol, table3.descripcion;
```

So you should:

- Not use `distinct` when using `group by`
- List all selected columns that you do not aggregate in the `group by` clause
- Better use join conditions which link the primary key with the foreign key and put filtering conditions in the `where` clause
- Use an analytic function like `row_number()` to check if you have a repeating value

Answer (score 0):

You are using group by without aggregation function

you don't need  group by for distinct (so you can remove the group by)

```
  select DISTINCT table1.rol, table3.descripcion 
  from table1 
  inner join table2 on (table2.IDUSUARIO = 1 and table1.IDUSUARIO = 1 ) 
  left join table3 on table3.rol = table1.rol 
  ORDER BY table1.rol
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing, the "what I want", is a data presentation concern. The picture implies that you want to do what is known in sqlplus as "eliminating duplicate (repeating) values from the *display* of the data".

```
SQL> break on rol nodup
SQL> select ....;
```

If you attempt to solve this by modifying the SQL statement text (i.e., pushing the presentation layer into the business logic), you will be asking for trouble. You'll end up writing code that is more difficult to prove correct and more difficult to explain to the maintainer.